# Layout Mode erases everything and takes me out of the app

Tags: modeling, rendering, blend-modes

When I switch to Layout Mode, it erases everything and takes me out of the app (luckily I saved). Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Do you mean when you change the workspace to *Layout*? using the top tab?